# Get a list of checked checbox values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subregion[]" value="North East" />North East
<input type="checkbox" name="subregion[]" value="North West" />North West
<input type="checkbox" name="subregion[]" value="Midlands" />Midlands
<input type="checkbox" name="subregion[]" value="South East" />South East
<input type="checkbox" name="subregion[]" value="South West" />South West
<input type="checkbox" name="subregion[]" value="Wales" />Wales
<input type="checkbox" name="subregion[]" value="Scotland" />Scotland
```

And I want to pass through a list of values of checked inputs to a php script using ajax. I just can't work out how to achieve it with jQuery?

Comment: Read this: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the array of values:

```
var checked = $('[name="subregion[]"]:checked').map(function() { 
  return $(this).val(); 
}).get();
```

If you're using `$.ajax` or a related method, you don't have to serialize or call `JSON.stringify`(*you can just use the array as a parameter value*).

Comment: If i alert(checked); I just get a blank alert box?

Answer (score 0):

Loop trough the checked checkboxes, add them to an array and convert it to a string:

```
var checked = [];   
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    checked.push($(this).val());
});
var checkedStr = JSON.stringify(checked);
```

Or serialize them like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo: jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYekQ/3/)**

If you are using CSS3, you can use the [`begins-with`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) selector, else you can use `name="subregion[]"`.

```js
function getSelectedSubregions() {
    var subregion = new Array();
    $(':checkbox:checked[name^="subregion"]').each(function() {
       subregion.push($(this).val());
    });
    return subregion;
}
```